# Get the average of another column, given conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following "source" dataframe

```
            Value
Date             
2022-01-01     26
2022-01-02     87
2022-01-03      4
2022-01-04     65
2022-01-05     89
2022-01-06     88
2022-01-07     82
2022-01-08     60
2022-01-09      8
2022-01-10     22
```

In another "output" dataframe, I have 4 columns defining 2 ranges of dates. As you can see, range1 is always defined, whilst range2 is defined only in certain rows:

```
  range1_lower range1_upper range2_lower range2_upper
0   2022-01-02   2022-01-03   2022-01-06   2022-01-07
1   2022-01-03   2022-01-06          NaN          NaN
```

In the output df I need to add an "average" column where, for each row, I get the average of the "Value" column of the source df, if the Date falls in **either** of the two ranges. This is something similar to the AVERAGEIFS function in Excel.

So, for example, for row 0 I need to get the average of all Values falling within range1 (2022-01-02 to 2022-01-03) or within range2 (2022-01-06 to 2022-01-07).

For row 1, since range2 is not defined,  I only need to get the average of all Values falling within range1 (2022-01-03 to 2022-01-06).

This is the expected output:

```
  range1_lower range1_upper range2_lower range2_upper  average
0   2022-01-02   2022-01-03   2022-01-06   2022-01-07    65.25
1   2022-01-03   2022-01-06          NaN          NaN    61.50
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cross` `merge` the two dataframes then filter out the dates that do not fall between the range limits then group by the range columns and aggregate `Value` with `mean`:

```
df = output.merge(source.reset_index(), how='cross')
df = df.query("range1_lower <= Date <= range1_upper or range2_lower <= Date <= range2_upper")
df = df.groupby([*output.columns], dropna=False)['Value'].mean().reset_index(name='avg')
```

---

```
print(df)

  range1_lower range1_upper range2_lower range2_upper    avg
0   2022-01-02   2022-01-03   2022-01-06   2022-01-07  65.25
1   2022-01-03   2022-01-06          NaT          NaT  61.50
```